# Ну могу подключиться к репозиторию github в VSCode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Сначала использовал один профиль в github, потом поменял его, соответственно из первого вышел. Даже VSCode снёс полностью с файлами настроек, подчистую. Однако при подключении к новому профилю он пишет `remote: Permission to <новый профиль> denied to <старый профиль>`. Откуда он его знает? Как мне решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Еле разобрался. Оказывается винда хранила мою учётную запись, с которой я так тщетно старался выйти. Если кому понадобится решение подобной проблему, вот ссылка https://htmlblog.github.io/permission-to-denied-to-git-error-403